# Google Search CSE open in same page - AJAX / iframe overlay

Tags: ajax, search, google-custom-search

I've got the google cse on my site to display results in the right place but when i click on them it opens in a new page, i want it to open in the same page but can't figure it out.

All the files are uploaded and the page can be found at

http://www.alwaystwisted.com/sandbox/stagecraft/template.html

Thanks in advance

Regards

Stu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the info and changed some of my javascript (the last bit within the page)

function OnLoad() { 


  var cseo=new CSEOverlay("016190657123569369479:3uma0emyzom", 


document.getElementById("searchbox_016190657123569369479:3uma0emyzom"), 


document.getElementById("results_016190657123569369479:3uma0emyzom")); 
cseo.searchControl.setLinkTarget(GSearch.LINK_TARGET_PARENT); 


} 


GSearch.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);

and it works...